# I cannot compile some gtk c code on ubuntu for windows

Tags: gtk, mingw, ubuntu-12.04

First of all I have to say that I am new to linux.
I use ubuntu and trying to compile some c code.
I learned gtk and compiled some programs with gcc but I want to make it for windows.
That's why I downloaded gtk for windows all in one bundle and put the include and lib folders into /usr/i686-w64-mingw32.
but when I try to compile my source code with mingw it says gtk/gtk.h not found.
what should I do?

Thank you everyone.

Comment: You may find real file paths of `gtk/*.h` files and add them to gcc's default libraries or rearrange your `#include` commands with real `#include "headerfile.h"` styled string.

Comment: when i change gtk/gtk.h to /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include... also the real path and then $ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc main.c `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags` `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs`
Package gtk+-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
In file included from main.c:1:0:
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32:21: fatal error: gdk/gdk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Either add the directory where your `pkg-config.exe` is to your `PATH`, or set the `PKG_CONFIG_DIR` environment variable to that.

Comment: can you write how I should compile my code. What should I write exactly to the terminal window? I added /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin to PATH variable and /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/pkgconfig to PKG_CONFIG_PATH. but when I try to compile the code with this command: $ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` main.c -o Impuls.exe `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`
main.c:1:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: What does `pkg-config --cflags --libs` return to you?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is REALLY old, but...

When cross-compiling you need to specify the sysroot with the "--sysroot" argument.

> `--sysroot=dir`: Use dir as the logical root directory for headers and
>   libraries. For example, if the compiler would normally search for
>   headers in /usr/include and libraries in /usr/lib, it will instead search
>   dir/usr/include and dir/usr/lib. [[ref]][1]

When you do this, the include paths etc. are all taken relative to the sysroot, in your case "/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/". Since you put the libraries in "lib" and the header files in "include" everything should just work, apart from any extra arguments that compiling with GTK may need.

If you look at the output of "pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0" then it should look like the following:

-pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2

If you ARE specifying the sysroot and still getting the errors that you report, then possibly you put the header files in the wrong folders. The native path for gtk.h is "/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h" so to cross-compile the version from the mingw GTK package should be copied to "/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h".

Lastly note that pkg-config gives you "-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include". If you specify the sysroot correctly, and put the header files in the locations described by pkg-config, this include path may still give you problems. The problem is that pkg-config is giving you the answer for native compilation and you want to cross-compile.